# Scrapy output issue

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am having issues displaying my items as i wanted. My code is as follows:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import request
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from texashealth.items import TexashealthItem

class texashealthspider(CrawlSpider):

    name="texashealth"
    allowed_domains=['jobs.texashealth.org']
    start_urls=['http://jobs.texashealth.org/search/?&q=&title=Filter%3A%20title&facility=Filter%3A%20facility&location=Filter%3A%20city&date=Filter%3A%20date']

    rules=(
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("search/",)), callback="parse_health", follow=True),
    #Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("startrow=\d",)),callback="parse_health",follow=True),
    )

    def parse_health(self, response):
        hxs=HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    titles=hxs.select('//tbody/tr/td')
    items = []

    for titles in titles:
        item=TexashealthItem()
        item['title']=titles.select('span[@class="jobTitle"]/a/text()').extract()
        item['link']=titles.select('span[@class="jobTitle"]/a/@href').extract()
        item['shifttype']=titles.select('span[@class="jobShiftType"]/text()').extract()
        item['location']=titles.select('span[@class="jobLocation"]/text()').extract()
        items.append(item)
    print items
    return items
```

and the output that is being displayed looks as follows in the json format:

```
[
    TexashealthItem(location=[], link=[u'/job/Fort-Worth-ULTRASONOGRAPHER-II-Job-TX-76101/31553900/'], shifttype=[], title=[u'ULTRASONOGRAPHER II Job']), 
    TexashealthItem(location=[], link=[], shifttype=[u'Texas Health Fort Worth'], title=[]), 
    TexashealthItem(location=[u'Fort Worth, TX, US'], link=[], shifttype=[], title=[]), 
    TexashealthItem(location=[], link=[], shifttype=[], title=[]), 
    TexashealthItem(location=[], link=[u'/job/Kaufman-RN-Acute-ICU-Full-Time-Kaufman-Job-TX-75142/35466900/'], shifttype=[], title=[u'RN--Telemetry--Full Time--Kaufman Job']), 
    TexashealthItem(location=[], link=[], shifttype=[u'Texas Health Kaufman'], title=[]), 
    TexashealthItem(location=[u'Kaufman, TX, US'], link=[], shifttype=[], title=[]), 
    TexashealthItem(location=[], link=[], shifttype=[], title=[]), 
    TexashealthItem(location=[], link=[u'/job/Fort-Worth-NURSE-PRACTITIONER-Occ-Med-Full-Time-Alliance-Job-TX-76101/35465400/'], shifttype=[], title=[u'NURSE PRACTITIONER-Occ Med-Full Time-Alliance Job']), 
    TexashealthItem(location=[], link=[], shifttype=[u'Texas Health Alliance'], title=[]), 
    TexashealthItem(location=[u'Fort Worth, TX, US'], link=[], shifttype=[], title=[]), 
    TexashealthItem(location=[], link=[], shifttype=[], title=[])
]
```

As you can see above, the parameters of the items are being displayed in separate intervals, that is, it displays the title and link in one line, and the rest of the output in other separate lines.

Can i get a solution so that i can display all the parameters in just one shot?

Thank you for your help

Comment: your output example comes from the `print items` line. You should comment it. Scrapy JSON serializer should do what you want when called through `scrapy crawl texashealth -t json -o output.json`

Comment: i have tried doing that already. But still i was getting the same result. Any ideas? Do you think it has something to do with the fields?

Comment: All I'm saying is that your sample output is not JSON. I'm not really getting what you mean by "items are being displayed in separate intervals". What is your expected output? for and example item?

Comment: Oh ok. So when you look at the output, you can see that the location is empty. As you scroll, you will also find the shift type field is empty. Only the link and the title are filled. But as you keep scrolling, the next entry contains the location and it is filled which is also the case with shifttype. They are being displayed as separate entries. I was wondering what might be the reason for that. You will also find a line where all the parameters and empty. So basically, the line that should show all the parameters in one line, is displaying the paramaters separately in separate intervals.

Comment: Ah, I see, you should loop on table rows -- `tr`s, and not table cells `td`s. I would use `hxs.select('//table[@id="searchresults"]/tbody/tr')` and then use `.//span...` in each loop iteration

Comment: Hi.. thank you so much.. your solution worked and gave me the perfect output..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop on table rows -- `tr` elements, and not table cells -- `td` elements.

I suggest you use `hxs.select('//table[@id="searchresults"]/tbody/tr')` and then use `.//span...` in each loop iteration

```
titles=hxs.select('//table[@id="searchresults"]/tbody/tr')
items = []
for titles in titles:
    item['title']=titles.select('.//span[@class="jobTitle"]/a/text()').extract()
    item['link']=titles.select('.//span[@class="jobTitle"]/a/@href').extract()
    item['shifttype']=titles.select('.//span[@class="jobShiftType"]/text()').extract()
    item['location']=titles.select('.//span[@class="jobLocation"]/text()').extract()
    items.append(item)
return items
```